# Cakephp RSS - Exhausting memory causing blank page for website

Tags: apache, cakephp, rss, crash, feed

When I put `Router::parseExtensions('rss');` to `routes.php`,  Apache crashes. So i can't make rss feed.
Any ideas ?

here is a [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/29931274/screen.jpg)

```
[Sat Jan 05 13:02:35.131540 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1576:tid 252] AH00428: Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Sat Jan 05 13:02:35.686942 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 1576:tid 252] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Jan 05 13:02:35.733742 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1576:tid 252] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 05 13:02:35.733742 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1576:tid 252] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Sat Jan 05 13:02:35.733742 2013] [core:notice] [pid 1576:tid 252] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Jan 05 13:02:35.733742 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1576:tid 252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4156
[Sat Jan 05 13:02:36.794544 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 4156:tid 264] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Jan 05 13:02:36.856944 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4156:tid 264] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

this is err log

Comment: When Apache crashes, it's always a good idea to start looking at your error log. What's in there?

Comment: Any recursive call in ur RSS page?

Comment: err log don't tell me nothing. And there's no recursive call, i got empty layout and view. With empty or not it crashes. Any time i call method with .rss ext it happens

Comment: this error is not related to the line of code you've put in the question - without any code at all your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

From the error screen, it appears your RSS may have too much data in it and it is exhausting the memory. You should check the data that is being returned and make sure it is limited.